# unable to pull a mongo document from python using find_one() with a par

Tags: python, mongodb, crud

Exploring python and mongo and cant sort out what I am doing wrong below

How do I pass a variable to a find_one() record?

The code below works but has the id value hard coded in the find_one() so is of no value but proves that connection code and function work

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

#connect to mongo database hosted on dedicated mongo server
#the script expects the host name to be in  /etc/hosts file


#Set up global variables here

mongo_server = "mongo_api"
mongo_port = "27017"
mongo_user = "admin"
mongo_passwd = ":mypassword@"
connect_string = "mongodb://"+ mongo_user 
                             + mongo_passwd 
                             + mongo_server 
                             + ":" 
                             + mongo_port


def get_page(page_no):
    connection = MongoClient(connect_string)    # equal to > show dbs
    db = connection.test_database # equal to > use test_database                
    pages = db.pages
    my_page = pages.find_one({"id": 2})  <----  VALUE HARD CODED WORKS
    return (my_page)

print get_page(1)
```

The code below fails or returns NONE I can't find a way to pass the function parameter page_no into find_one() function to pull a record back

I have tried to convert page_no to a string etc to no avail struggling a bit here.
In the code snippet below I have included a few of the variants I have tried to pass the value of page number into the find_one() request to no avail.

```
def get_page(page_no):
    index_val = str(page_no)
    connection = MongoClient(connect_string)    # equal to > show dbs
    db = connection.test_database # equal to > use test_database                
    pages = db.pages
    # NONE OF THESE VARIANTS WORK OTHERS I HAVE TRIED
    my_page = pages.find_one({"id": page_no})  <-- TRYING TO USE PARAMETER FAILS
    my_page = pages.find_one({"id": str(page_no)})
    my_page = pages.find_one({"id": index_val})

    return (my_page)

print get_page(1)
```

I either get an error or a NONE

BTW the password above is not my real password I thought I would leave the connection string in for others to see how I did it.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Show us the same query in the mongo shell. Something like `use test_database` followed by `db.test_database.findOne({'id':5})`.

Comment: It looks good. Are you sure you are using correct database / collection?

Comment: @zero323 "the top code works fine but has the value of the page id hard coded, its only when I try to pass that value through the function that if falls over, the database / collection code has to be right.  No point doing it from the mongo shell because it would be hard coded :(

Comment: Actually there is point in doing that in shell. Example data = reproducible example. Right now there is no way to reproduce your problem. If you use BSON numeric types for id `pages.find_one({"id": page_no})` works fine, if you use strings `pages.find_one({"id": str(2)})` works as expected. Wrapped in a function or not.

Comment: @zero323 Good point  and I agree calling it from a shell it helps you debug, but I had it working with a hard value, I have worked out the problem but it wont let me post until after eight hours Thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved and thought I would post for others.  I may have confused people including myself, to be clear I added my own primary key and called it **id**, this was in addition to the mongo provided index field  refered to as  **_id**, you can see how it might get confusing.

Clearly it's not a good idea to name your own internal primary key with the same name as the mongo provided one.

In the end this was caused by two problems, one was architectural which would not have been obvious to readers of the question and the other was that the parameter needed to be cast as an int

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

#connect to mongo database hosted on dedicated mongo server
#the script expects the mongo_server host name to be in  /etc/hosts file


#Set up global variables here

mongo_server = "mongo_api"
mongo_port = "27017"
mongo_user = "admin"
mongo_passwd = ":mypassword@"
connect_string = "mongodb://"+ mongo_user 
                             + mongo_passwd 
                             + mongo_server 
                             + ":" 
                             + mongo_port
# the above connect_string looks like
# mongodb://admin:mypassword@mongo_api:27017
# when formed


    def get_page(page_no):
    connection = MongoClient(connect_string)    # equal to > show dbs
    db = connection.test_database # equal to > use test_database                
    pages = db.pages
    my_page = pages.find_one({"id": int(page_no)})  <---- change to INT   
    return (my_page)


print get_page(1)
```

Thanks to those who responded.